# Google Calendar Appointment Slots booking event trigger

Tags: google-analytics, google-calendar-api, google-tag-manager

I'm implementing google calendar's appointment booking slots iframe on my website so people can book an appointment. i'd like to be able to track the bookings as an event in google tag manager to  measure the conversions on the page. The appointment booking ui is in an iframe, and it doent look like GTM can detect anything emitted form it. Hubspot's meeting booking iframe has a way to create a GTM listener with a custom peice of JS. I'm wondering if anyone knows how this can be done for the google calendar one.

i tried creating an event listener for the iframe but it didnt capture anything.